# azure powershell generating Account key error

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I want to create a container through Windows PowerShell and therefore try to obtain the account key via

```
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName | %{ $_.Key1 }
```

### Getting the error

```
New-AzureStorageContext : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'StorageAccountKey'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName | ? { $_.KeyName -eq 'Key1' } | % { $_.Value }
```

The problem is that the result is not a hashtable but a .NET generic list so it is not possible to access the value directly via the key name.
[image: .NET generic list instead of hashtable]